# Select all columns from Json Array string in oracle

Tags: json, plsql, oracle12c

I have a json array string like below

```
[{a:100},{a:200},{a:300},{a:400}]
```

Passing it as a CLOB input parameter to the Stored procedure

How can i get a tabular output like below with in sql so that i can bulk insert in a table

```
Value
-----------
100
200
300
400
```

I have tried some examples mentioned at oracle docs but unable to find the working example with above mentioned output.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`JSON_TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE destination ( a NUMBER );
```

**PL/SQL**:

```
DECLARE
  your_input_parameter CLOB := '[{a:100},{a:200},{a:300},{a:400}]';
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO destination ( a )
    SELECT a
    FROM   JSON_TABLE(
             your_input_parameter,
             '$[*]'
             COLUMNS a NUMBER PATH '$.a'
           );
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM destination;
```

```
|   A |
| --: |
| 100 |
| 200 |
| 300 |
| 400 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ebf44741e0c96279c4d2b5282c5b5e2b)*